# Tikz's drop shadow key creates solid shape for curved path instead of a shadow - How to create a shadow?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm in the process of making a glyph. I want the final shape to have a shadow.

Creating a shadow for the arrow tip works as intended. Making a shadow under the curved path at the bottom, does not. A weird solid gray filling is created instead when I issue the `drop shadow` key. How do I get the shadow in the right place*, just like the arrow tip?

---

- = An arbitrary offset will work for me. I used `shadow xshift=.725pt, shadow yshift=-.725pt` for the arrow tip.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={1pt -15pt 1pt 1pt},convert={density=3000,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shadows}
\tikzfading[name=fade,right color=black!10, left color=black]
\definecolor{rgray}{RGB}{188,188,214}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[path fading=fade, opacity=.5, drop shadow={shadow scale=.5, shadow xshift=-1.6pt, shadow yshift=1.5pt,
opacity=.5, fill=black}, fill=white, draw=rgray] (1.475,0.11) .. controls (1.45,.825) and (1.45,0.9875) .. (2,1);% how to get a shadow here?
\draw[path fading=fade, draw=rgray!100!black!90] (1.4375,.88) .. controls (1.45,.85) and (1.45,1.15) .. (2,1.2);
\draw[drop shadow={shadow scale=1, shadow xshift=.725pt, shadow yshift=-.725pt,
opacity=.5, fill=rgray!47}, fill=white, draw=rgray!50] (2,1) -- (2,.95) -- (2.23,1.1) -- (2,1.25) -- (2,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some attempt made in a hurry. Hence some fine tuning may be needed.

```
\documentclass[border={1pt -15pt 1pt 1pt},convert={density=3000,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shadows}
\tikzfading[name=fade,right color=black!10, left color=black]
\definecolor{rgray}{RGB}{188,188,214}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[path fading=fade, postaction={drop shadow={shadow scale=1, shadow xshift=0.5pt, shadow yshift=-0.5pt, opacity=.8, fill=gray!40}}, fill opacity=.9, draw=rgray] 
(1.475,0.11) .. controls (1.45,.825) and (1.45,0.9875) .. (2,1)
-- (2,1) -- (2,.95) -- (2.23,1.1) -- (2,1.25) -- (2,1.2) 
.. controls (1.45,1.1) and (1.45,1.3) .. (1.475,0.011);
\path[fill=white]
(1.475,0.11) .. controls (1.45,.825) and (1.45,0.9875) .. (2,1)
-- (2,1) -- (2,.95) -- (2.23,1.1) -- (2,1.25) -- (2,1.2)
.. controls (1.45,1.1) and (1.45,1.3) .. (1.475,0.011);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. The `postaction` key fixed this. What's the difference between `postaction` and the regular key? There must be a reasoning behind your choice and I'd like to know it. :-)

Comment: @1010011010: `postaction` key delays things until the `\draw` is over. Hence your `fade` is applied to shadow too.